# Type of statistical test for categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, repeated-measures

What test am I supposed to use in this case:

- Categorical outcome [correct, partially incorrect, incorrect]
- Categorical predictors:

  - Condition [2, 5 and 10 presentations of an image].
  - Time in which they were tested after the presentation [1 hour, 1 week, 1 month].

Condition was between subjects and time within subjects. Each participant was tested for 6 images (so I have 6 correct/incorrect/partially correct responses every time I tested them).

What I want to know is if they will have less correct after a month compared to the first test (1 hour after the presentation), and if the number of presentations makes a difference.

I though I needed to do a chi-squared test because all my variables are categorical, but my outcome is not yes/no or correct/incorrect. It has three levels instead. And I don't know if I should average the 0s, 1s and 2s OR add them up and treat it as a continuous variable ranging from 0 to 12 per time of test, and use an ANOVA. Since I'm measuring the same people three times, could I also use linear mixed models?

I am using R, in case that's relevant.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordered categorical data is referred to as **ordinal**, this is in contrast with unordered categorical data (e.g. 'Alive' 'Dead'), which is coined **nominal**. You can try to fit an ordinal logistic or probit regression for your use case where the outcome is ordinal. This is explained on [this link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/), using R.

Quoting from the link, the options you have are:

> **Ordered logistic regression**: the focus of the link above.
>
> **OLS regression**: This analysis is problematic because the assumptions of OLS are violated when it is used with a non-interval outcome variable.
>
> **ANOVA**: If you use only one continuous predictor, you could “flip” the model around so that, say, gpa was the outcome variable and apply
> was the predictor variable. Then you could run a one-way ANOVA. This
> isn’t a bad thing to do if you only have one predictor variable (from
> the logistic model), and it is continuous.
>
> **Multinomial logistic regression**: This is similar to doing ordered logistic regression, except that it is assumed that there is no order
> to the categories of the outcome variable (i.e., the categories are
> nominal). The downside of this approach is that the information
> contained in the ordering is lost.
>
> **Ordered probit regression**: This is very, very similar to running an ordered logistic regression. The main difference is in the interpretation of the coefficients.